# Preload in cocos2d v3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, objective-c, assets

I'm trying to create a preload, but i don't know how to implement the code of this [topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47247/cocos2d-patterns-for-simple-texture-management) in cocos2d iphone v3. Since CCTextureCache has changed to CCTexture, and doesn't have sharedTextureCache property anymore.

```
@interface TextureHelper : NSObject
+ (void) preloadTextures;
+ (CCTexture2D *) textureForImageNamed:(NSString *) imageName;
@end

@implementation TextureHelper
+ (CCTexture2D *) textureForImageNamed:(NSString *) imageName {
    return [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:imageName];
}

+ (void) preloadTextures {
    // or could read from a directory...
    NSArray *imageNames = @[
    @"myImage1.png",
    @"myImage2.png"
    ];

    for (NSString *imageName in imageNames)
        [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:imageName];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way is to load the textures and keep a reference to them ourself. You could reimplement your code to something like:

```
@interface TextureHelper : NSObject
- (void) preloadTextures;
- (CCTexture2D *) textureForImageNamed:(NSString *) imageName;
@end

@implementation TextureHelper
{
    NSArray * loadedTextures;
}

- (CCTexture *) textureForImageNamed:(NSString *) imageName 
{
    // TODO: Lookup loadedTextures and find the requested one.
    // Return a pointer to it. Probably use a NSDictionary...
}

- (CCSprite *) spriteForImageNamed:(NSString *) imageName
{
    // Create a sprite using the whole contents of the texture:
    CCTexture * tex = [self textureForImageNamed:imageName];
    if (!tex)
    {
        // TODO: Handle failure
    }

    CCSpriteFrame * frame = [tex createSpriteFrame];
    CCSprite * sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:frame];
    return sprite;
}

- (void) preloadTextures 
{
    NSArray *imageNames = @[
        @"myImage1.png",
        @"myImage2.png"
        // your textures here ... 
    ];

    for (NSString *imageName in imageNames)
    {
        CCTexture * tex = [CCTexture textureWithFile:imageName];
        [loadedTextures addObject:tex];
    }
}

@end
```

You'll probably want to use a dictionary to store the textures and index them by name, but you can get the ideia from the code above. CCSprite also has *spriteWithTexture / initWithTexture* that you can use in conjunction.

Comment: Thanks! How should I reference the loadedTextures when creating the CCSprite? I'm trying @"img.png" and img.png and none works

Comment: Sorry @FilipeFerminiano, I didn't quite follow your question. I've edited the code to include a method that directly creates a sprite with the contents of a preloaded texture. If your problem is that the textures are not being found/loaded, then you probably forgot to add them to your project on Xcode.